# Javascript get file name is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly i'll need to apologize as I'm **very new** to coding and this might be very easy to be solved

I need to get the name of the file and display it within the blue box. My js script's last part does not work:

```
var filename = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();    
$("#label_span").text(filename);
```

The message below was displayed when I tried it using the codesnippet

> {
>     "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined",
>     "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>     "lineno": 109,
>     "colno": 19
>   }

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#file").on("change", function() {
    var files = $(this)[0].files;

    if (files.length >= 2) {
      $("#label_span").text(files.length + " files ready to upload");
    } else {
      var filename = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
      $("#label_span").text(filename);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-family: 16px;
}

h1 {
  color: #3c4954;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

p {
  color: #a4b0b9;
  line-height: 200%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.form-div {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.input-label {
  background: #009688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-label:hover {
  background: #26a69a;
  cursor: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#file {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Custom Input</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test_Impor.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body align="center">
  <header>
    <h1>Custom Input</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="form-div">
    <form>
      <label for="file" class="input-label">
     <i class = "fa fa-upload"></i>
     <span id = "label_span">Select files to upload</span>
    </label>
      <input id="file" type="file" multiple="true" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="Test_Import.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the `files` array is an object with a `name` property. So just access the first element of the array and get its name.

You don't need to use `split()`, as it just contains the name, not the full path.

And instead of `$(this)[0]` you can just use `this`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#file").on("change", function() {

    var files = this.files;

    if (files.length >= 2) {
      $("#label_span").text(files.length + " files ready to upload");
    } else if (files.length == 1) {
      var filename = files[0].name;
      $("#label_span").text(filename);
    } else {
      $("#label_span").text("Select files to upload");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-family: 16px;
}

h1 {
  color: #3c4954;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

p {
  color: #a4b0b9;
  line-height: 200%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.form-div {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.input-label {
  background: #009688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-label:hover {
  background: #26a69a;
  cursor: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#file {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Custom Input</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test_Impor.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body align="center">

  <header>
    <h1>Custom Input</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="form-div">
    <form>
      <label for="file" class="input-label">
     <i class = "fa fa-upload"></i>
     <span id = "label_span">Select files to upload</span>
    </label>
      <input id="file" type="file" multiple="true" />

    </form>
  </div>




  <script src="Test_Import.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hopefully Mr Barmar you don't mind another question, what should I do when I want the span text to return to its default value (in this case: Logo + "select files to upload") when I clicked cancel upon choosing file to be opened. I have a feeling " $("#label_span").text(""); " <- this line is suppose to do something when there is no file

Comment: Yeah, change that empty string to the message you want. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Weird enough though it works on codesnippet. However, when I launched it from localhost:8080/xxxx, the last string is not displayed when cancel is clicked (using usbwebserver and launched it as a .php file).

Comment: I'm not sure why Javascript would work differently depending on where the file was loaded from. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, there werent any problems, the string inside span was cleared each time i click cancel. The code works on jsfiddle too. I also tried to give it conditions but nope, nothing worked

Comment: The string inside was cleared? Then the code must be running to replace it, you must still be running the old version that wasn't putting back the "select files" message. Make sure you cleared your cache.

Comment: It worked! Thanks sir once again. Anyways, using jQuery 3.x vs jQuery 1.x doesnt matter right? Except for its compatibility right?

Comment: No, there's nothing here that depends on the version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `e` to your event callback function

```
$("#file").on("change", function(e) {...}
```